# Multiline hidden text

Tags: support, markdown, spoilers

For some questions, you think the user might learn more if you don't let them read the entire proof right away.

So you use

> this.

But I never managed to get a multiline one. Just like the quote block, it ignores newlines. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: I agree we should use gender neutral words in situations like this. But bumping a three years old thread just for that? C'mon, that's just blatant badge-hunting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can begin every line with `>!` and end it with two spaces.

> To be, or not to be: that is the question:
>  Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
>  The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune,
>  Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,
>  And by opposing end them?

> (I think this was about moderator elections at Elsinore.SE)