# Formatting problem with "invisible" comments

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, spoilers

I posted an answer and tried to make some of my hints invisible
(but visible when you mouse-over them).

Formatting didn't quite work, and I split the comment into three lines making only the first and the third invisible, as follows.

> If $K=1-\frac{K_1}{2K_2}$ then clearly $K<1$.

Let $\lambda=\frac1{2K_2}$ so $K=1-\lambda K_1$.

> Then $0\le\frac12=1-\frac12=1-\lambda K_2\le1-\lambda F'(c)\leq1-\lambda K_1=K<1$.

If I try to make all three lines invisible, this is what I get (and it is obviously not what I want).

> ! If $K=1-\frac{K_1}{2K_2}$ then clearly $K<1$.
>
> ! Let $\lambda=\frac1{2K_2}$ so $K=1-\lambda K_1$.
>
> ! Then $0\le\frac12=1-\frac12=1-\lambda K_2\le1-\lambda F'(c)\leq1-\lambda K_1=K<1$.

Or if I combine all three into one, again I don't get the result I want:

> ! If $K=1-\frac{K_1}{2K_2}$ then clearly $K<1$.
> Let $\lambda=\frac1{2K_2}$ so $K=1-\lambda K_1$.
> Then $0\le\frac12=1-\frac12=1-\lambda K_2\le1-\lambda F'(c)\leq1-\lambda K_1=K<1$.

There is either something that doesn't properly work as intended, or I do not understand the proper way to format. The answer where all this occurred (just in case you would end up voting :) is at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406622

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9):

This seems to work. (Instead of `<br>` you can simply use two spaces, if you prefer.)

```
>! If $K=1-\frac{K_1}{2K_2}$ then clearly $K<1$.<br>
>! Let $\lambda=\frac1{2K_2}$ so $K=1-\lambda K_1$.<br>
>! Then $0\le\frac12=1-\frac12=1-\lambda K_2\le1-\lambda F'(c)\leq1-\lambda K_1=K<1$.<br>
```

> If $K=1-\frac{K_1}{2K_2}$ then clearly $K<1$.
>  Let $\lambda=\frac1{2K_2}$ so $K=1-\lambda K_1$.
>  Then $0\le\frac12=1-\frac12=1-\lambda K_2\le1-\lambda F'(c)\leq1-\lambda K_1=K<1$.

This was the suggestion from an older thread on meta: [Multiline hidden text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9454)

You could also try some of the workarounds suggested in this question: [Consecutive spoiler blocks (>!) are shown as blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144824). (And in other related posts [which are linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/144824).)